# How to retrieve images from script result in C#

Tags: python, c#

I have a c# application, and it need to call a python script which will generate some images. Is it possible c# application could retrieve images directly from memory? I want to avoid saving images to hard drive since it may slow down the application.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at using IronPython to run your Python script?

Comment: Or maybe a communication between [shared memory in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) and [shared memory in c#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharedMemory/).